# File Name & Year & Last modified date

Tags: powershell

Based on the year in the filename -  max last modified date file to be there and remaining to move to archive.

Example: 2016 1 file should be there remaining should go archive same for 2017.

I tried

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate'
$destdir   = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate\Archive'
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
    Sort-Object {$_.Basename.Split('-')[1,0]} 

Select-Object -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force
```

```
Mode       Last Modified date       Length     Filename

-a---         6/25/2018  12:08 AM      31744 abc_2016_2 - Copy - Copy.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:07 AM      31744 abc_2016_2 - Copy.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:06 AM      31744 abc_2017_1.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:07 AM      31744 abc_2017_2.xls
-a---         6/25/2018  12:05 AM      31744 abc_2017_3.xls
```

Suggestion are welcome in the form of dynamically and not hard coded.

Comment: There is a typo in your split command, it should be an underscore not a dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first halfway understandable description (from you and your several colleagues)  of the task to accomplish.

Let me try to translate:

- The files in the source folder shall be grouped by the year extracted from the
  filename
- all files should be archived except the newest one from each group (determined by LastWriteDate)

<s>Un</s>tested script

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate'
$destdir   = 'C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate\Archive'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir*.xls |
  Group-Object {$_.Basename.Split('_')[1]} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
      Select-Object -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force -WhatIf
  }
```

To first check the outcome I added th eparameter `-WhatIf` to the Move-Item.
If all looks OK remove the  `-WhatIf`

Intermediate result after the Group-Object (on my ramdrive A:) :

```
Count Name  Group
----- ----  -----
    2 2016  {A:\abc_2016_2 - Copy - Copy.xls, A:\abc_2016_2 - Copy.xls}
    3 2017  {A:\abc_2017_1.xls, A:\abc_2017_2.xls, A:\abc_2017_3.xls}
```

**EDIT to follow [lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit)s [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114863/file-name-year-last-modified-date/51115042?noredirect=1#comment89219436_51115042)

here a variant extracting the year with a regular expression using a (capture group)**

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir*.xls |
  Where-Object BaseName -match '_(20\d{2})_\d' |
    Group-Object {$Matches[1]} | ForEach-Object {
      $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Destination $destdir -Force -WhatIf
    }
```

Comment: This looks like it will work on the filenames given by the OP. It assumes there cannot be a LOW LINE (underscore) before the year value. If a file `abc_sun_2018_1.xls` appeared, this might have difficulties. What about something with `$_.BaseName -match '.*_(\d{4})_\d*'`, then use `$Matches[1]` for the year.

Comment: @lit good point I was also taking this into account but wanted to stay as close to OPs script as possible. I'll incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @lit I think you are the most genius person among the great people. let me try this ...thanks

Comment: Oh God... you are seriously genius...nobody can do it on this earth planet.....that you did it

Comment: @vijit - Thank you for your complement, but I can assure you that it is not true. I am just another one out there trying to make things work.